# Get the title of the toast when the toast notification is removed from action center in UWP

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, toast

I have an application which is able to send three different types of local toasts,using the notifier.Show(toast) method.I need to track the notification title and current time when the notification is removed from the action center.I have registered my background task as "ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger(application_Id)".my background task is triggered when the notification is removed from the action center,but the details of the removed notification is not available in the background task.so,I am unable to get the title of the removed toast.can anyone help me to overcome this problem?.

Answer (score 0):

[Notification Listener Documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/05/26/notification-listener-documentation-windows-10) should be able to get the removed notifications detailed information.